# Reverse Android native lib

Tags: android, llvm

I am wondering how to reverse Android native lib. Its covered with ollvm so the code is awful and I can't understand anything
I can use Frida but not Frida stalker (got kicked every time trying to connect)
So I am asking how u deal with such libs? Maybe some deobfuscators or something like this

Answer (score 0):

If the LLVM obfuscation you are dealing with is mainly based on control flow flattening you can give a try to this tool : https://github.com/mrT4ntr4/MODeflattener.git